# Java Android Eclipse AVD "Unfortunately, <project name> has stopped."

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

In the eclipse/android AVD, I get "Unfortunately,  has stopped"

I have checked other Qs about this, but none helped.

I assume it is my code that is faulty, because when I comment the code out, it runs fine. However, the android code-checker thingy shows no errors.

This is my code:

```
public TextView TextView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    setTextView();
}

public void setTextView(){
    TextView tv = (TextView);
    findViewById(R.id.textView1); 
    tv.setText("4");
}
```

I tried this aswell, but the same happened

```
public TextView TextView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    TextView tv = (TextView);
    findViewById(R.id.textView1); 
    tv.setText("4"); 
}
```

I'm not sure whether the structure of my code is correct either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 TextView tv = (TextView);
```

Makes `tv` as `null` and when you do `tv.set...` it throws `NullPointerException`.

Try below code.

```
  TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1); 
    tv.setText("4");
```

Answer (score 1):

> "However, the android code-checker thingy shows no errors."

if you are referring to the way that eclipse highlights errors in your code before you run, it will not catch an error like this. Your error is a runtime error, which means that your code is perfectly capable of compiling.

the checking that ecplise does will only catch errors that cause your code to be unable to compile (largely typo errors).

To catch runtime errors you need to open the Logcat view in your ecplise and watch the logs as your application runs / force closes.

there will be a stack trace in there that explains what has happened.